# webpage Flickering when scrolling to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

On the web-site I'm working on  there is a flicker effect (it is impossible to reach the end of the page since it returns one step back) when the page is scrolled down to the end. If during this flicker problem I re-size the browser window (normally reduce the size) all works fine. I noticed that this problem is  browser dependent it flicker at specific width or height .when i scroll down to screen my screen start flickering i do RND but but none of them solve my problem please tell anyone if know.

```js
  POTENZA.isSticky = function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $('.header-sticky').addClass('is-sticky');
      } else {
        $('.header-sticky').removeClass('is-sticky');
      }
    });
  };
```

```css
.header.is-sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1c1a1f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px rgb(28 26 31 / 10%);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px rgb(28 26 31 / 10%);
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header header-style-02 header-sticky">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-expand-lg px-2">
        <div class="container-fluid position-relative px-0 button-align">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><i class="fas fa-align-left"></i></button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://ogoultutor.test/index ">
                <img src="/images/logo_web.png" style="padding-right: 42px;" alt="logo">
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-sticky" href="/index">
                <img src="/images/logo_web.png" style="padding-right: 42px;" alt="logo">
            </a>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/course-list">Courses</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/teachers">Tutors</a>
                    </li>

                    <li><a class="nav-link" href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" style="margin-left: 13px" href="/faqs">FAQs</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link" style="margin-left: 13px" href="/tutorials">Tutorials</a></li>

                    <li style="padding-right: 7px;padding-left: 7px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <form id="language-form" method="post" action="https://ogoultutor.test/change_app_language">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="DtOTSduu1JBtI5SczCT7CDMo5TcZyaxf2yzEoR4m">                            <select class="basic-select form-control size-increase select2-hidden-accessible" name="language" onchange="$('#language-form').submit()" data-select2-id="1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                <option value="en" selected="" data-select2-id="3">English</option>
                                <option value="ar">عربى</option>
                                <option value="es">Española</option>
                                <option value="fr">français</option>
                                <option value="hi">हिन्दी</option>
                            </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="2" style="width: auto;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-language-ui-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-language-ui-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="English">English</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                        </form>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="woo-action">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                            <li class="navdropdown nav-item">
                            <span class="nav-link">
                                                                
                                (Tutor)
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    
                                                                                            <!-- <a href="https://ogoultutor.test/tutor-detail/54"><li class="user"><i class="fa fa-user " style="padding-right: 0.5rem;"></i>Mark Hall</li></a> -->
                                                        <ul class="nav navbar-navv">
                                <li class="dropdown nav-item ">
                                    <a class="nav-link navdropdown" href="https://ogoultutor.test/tutor-detail/54" data-toggle="dropdown">Mark Hall
                                                                                    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle listimg_2" src="/images/teachers/FB_IMG_1508047248246.jpg" alt="">
                                                                            </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu AR-left_dropDown_profile" style="left:21%;">
                                        <li class="border-bottom-1">
                                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">

                                                    <ul class="list-unstyled mt-lg-1">
                                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ogoultutor.test/tutor-detail/54" style="color:#edab30; !important;"><span>My Profile</span></a>
                                                            <hr>
                                                        </li>

                                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/booking_tutor" style="color:#edab30 !important;"><span>Your Classes</span></a>
                                                            <hr>
                                                        </li>


                                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/lecture_history" style="color:#edab30 !important;"><span>Tutor History</span></a>
                                                            <hr>
                                                        </li>

                                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/my_earning" style="color:#edab30 !important;"><span>My Earnings</span></a>
                                                            <hr>
                                                        </li>

                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        
                                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/change_password" style="color:#edab30 !important;"><span>Change Password</span></a>
                                                            <hr>
                                                        </li>

                                                        <li>
                                                            <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#edab30 !important;" class="dropdown-item" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"><span>Sign Out</span></a>
                                                        <!-- <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-label-brand btn-sm btn-bold" href="https://ogoultutor.test/logout" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" style="color: #EDAB30;">Sign Out</a> -->
                                                            <form id="logout-form" action="https://ogoultutor.test/logout" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="DtOTSduu1JBtI5SczCT7CDMo5TcZyaxf2yzEoR4m">                                                            </form>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                                                <!-- <div class="kt-notification__custom">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-label-brand btn-sm btn-bold" href="https://ogoultutor.test/logout" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" style="color: #EDAB30;">Sign Out</a>
                  <form id="logout-form" action="https://ogoultutor.test/logout" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="DtOTSduu1JBtI5SczCT7CDMo5TcZyaxf2yzEoR4m">                        </form>
                      </div> -->
                                                            <li class="cart dropdown">
                        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="cart-icon"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i><span id="cart-icon">3</span></span></button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu-right AR-left_dropDown_bell" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <ul class="cart-list pl-0" id="lecture_table"><li class="d-flex"><img class="img-fluid mr-3" src="/images/shop/02.jpg"><a href="/booking_tutor"><div class="cart-info"><span class="d-block"><b>Mechanics</b></span><span class="d-block"><b>husnain</b></span></div></a></li><li class="d-flex"><img class="img-fluid mr-3" src="/images/shop/02.jpg"><a href="/booking_tutor"><div class="cart-info"><span class="d-block"><b>Mechanics</b></span><span class="d-block"><b>mark hanery</b></span></div></a></li><li class="d-flex"><img class="img-fluid mr-3" src="/images/students/Koala.jpg"><a href="/booking_tutor"><div class="cart-info"><span class="d-block"><b>Mechanics</b></span><span class="d-block"><b>Zain</b></span></div></a></li></ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                                                        </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

you migh be don't have much content on that page
Solution 1 : increase height of page
Solutiion 2 : on that particular page which you face flicker issue change header styles properites fixed to  position relative

Comment: yes I don't have much content it is occurring on those pages which have less content and they are multiple its requirement to made header fixed on the top when scrolling down I can't change its property fixed to relative

Comment: ok then change  $(this).scrollTop() > 150 to $(this).scrollTop() > 250 or may be based on your page height

Comment: I had a class is-sticky that implement through JS when the condition become true that was the problem. I just replaced it with BootStrap default class sticky-top it works for me. thanks for your time and answer.